# How to check all checkboxes in a Views exposed filter by default?

Tags: views

I'm using the Views and Better Exposed Filters modules to allow users to select age ranges like this:

[image: checkboxes of age ranges]

This view functions as a search page.  However, users are confused because if they simply hit *Apply*, all age groups are searched even though no age groups are checked.  For this reason, I would like to show all age groups as selected by default to make it clear that all age groups are searched by default.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you click on the filter in the Views admin UI to get to the "Configure filter criterion" popup, and then select all of the options for the filter like so:

[image]

Then they appear ticked by default when you access the View page.

Comment: Ok, I see my problem now-- I also had the "Limit list to selected items" box checked.  If that box is checked, then the items on the exposed filter will not be shown as checked.  To me, that looks like a bug...

Comment: It's a huge bug in fact.  The result of this bug is that every single content type gets pulled from the system, rather than the items you "limited the filter to".

Comment: There must be something in the issue queue for this, if anyone finds it, post the link here.

Comment: Here's one issue on this at least: https://drupal.org/node/510068